# How can I get user input of type integer in dart?

Tags: dart, input, stdin

How can I get user input of type integer in **dart**? I tried the following, but does not work.

```
int calculate(){
    int x = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
    int y = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
    return x + y;
}
```

I got this error:

> Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter
> type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.**